# iOS - Using Push Notifications in UITests Target

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, configuration, xcode-ui-testing

I am required to use push notifications in AppUITests. Is there any way to add/update settings of a AppUITests target using custom entitlement file?

Comment: Why does your UI Testing target require the use of Push Notifications. Doesn't your app receive the push notifications?

Comment: My apps working fine. I need to test push on auto ui test. isn't there any way? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Xcode 9 you can use Remote Notifications in your UITests by using a framework called [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher)

To test Remote Notifications in your UITests you have to do the following steps:

1. Add NWPusher to your UITest target
2. Download a APN development certificate from Apple's Dev Center and add it to your Keychain (if it is not already there)
3. Export the certificate as p12 file
4. Write the test

I tried that out and this is my test file:

My demo app presents three different modal view controllers depending on the push notification it receives. So there are three different push notifications in this test.

```
import XCTest
import PusherKit

class PushNotificationUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    func testPushNotifications() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments.append("isRunningUITests")
        app.launch()

        // access to the springboard (to be able to tap the notification later)
        let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

        // dismiss the system dialog if it pops up
        allowPushNotificationsIfNeeded()

        // get the current deviceToken from the app
        let deviceToken = app.staticTexts.element(matching: .any, identifier: "tokenLabel").label

        // close app
        XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
        sleep(1)

        // trigger red Push Notification
        triggerPushNotification(
            withPayload: "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello Red\"}, \"vcType\":\"red\"}",
            deviceToken: deviceToken)

        // tap on the notification when it is received
        springboard.otherElements["PUSHNOTIFICATION, now, Hello Red"].tap()

        // check if the red view controller is shown
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Red"].exists)

        // dismiss modal view controller and close app
        app.buttons["Close"].tap()
        XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
        sleep(1)

        // trigger green Push Notification
        triggerPushNotification(
            withPayload: "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello Green\"}, \"vcType\":\"green\"}",
            deviceToken: deviceToken)

        // tap on the notification when it is received
        springboard.otherElements["PUSHNOTIFICATION, now, Hello Green"].tap()

        // check if the green view controller is shown
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Green"].exists)

        // dismiss modal view controller and close app
        app.buttons["Close"].tap()
        XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
        sleep(1)

        // trigger blue Push Notification
        triggerPushNotification(
            withPayload: "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello Blue\"}, \"vcType\":\"blue\"}",
            deviceToken: deviceToken)

        // tap on the notification when it is received
        springboard.otherElements["PUSHNOTIFICATION, now, Hello Blue"].tap()

        // check if the blue view controller is shown
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Blue"].exists)

        // dismiss modal view controller 
        app.buttons["Close"].tap()
    }
}

extension XCTestCase {
    func triggerPushNotification(withPayload payload: String, deviceToken: String) {
        let uiTestBundle = Bundle(for: PushNotificationUITests.self)
        guard let url = uiTestBundle.url(forResource: "pusher.p12", withExtension: nil) else { return }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let pusher = try NWPusher.connect(withPKCS12Data: data, password: "pusher", environment: .auto)
            try pusher.pushPayload(payload, token: deviceToken, identifier: UInt(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(999))))
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func allowPushNotificationsIfNeeded() {
        addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "“RemoteNotification” Would Like to Send You Notifications") { (alerts) -> Bool in
            if(alerts.buttons["Allow"].exists){
                alerts.buttons["Allow"].tap();
            }
            return true;
        }
        XCUIApplication().tap()
    }
}
```

I wrote a detailed [blogpost](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/testing-push-notifications-with-xcode-uitests/) about this and you can download the demo [here](https://github.com/pixeldock/PushNotificationUITests)